# c# linq object to javascript output

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

In my signalr application i am sending notification using following Hub method:-
C# code:-

```
 public void Updatecid(int uid, string connid)
    {
        var ntf = ege.notifications.Where(u => u.UserID == uid).ToList();
        Clients[connid].addData(ntf);
    }
```

Javascript Code Client Side:-

```
connection.addData = function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var element = data[i];
                $('#notiadd').append("<li>" + element.NotificationTitle + "<a href='" + element.NotificationLink + "'>Click Here</a><input type='hidden' value='" + element.ID + "' /> <a href='#' class='delnoti'>X</a> </li>");
            }
        };
```

Getting Output:-

safasfasfa Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

undefined Click Here X

You can check in output that only first notification is coming and remain are undefined.
I debug application in that C# code sending complete data but javascript make some output error.

Comment: can you add a console.log("element", i, element) befire you call the append function and report what you get?

Comment: to Bart:-element 0 Object {$id="1", ID=98, NotificationTitle="safasfasfa", ...}
element 1 Object {$ref="3"}
element 2 Object {$ref="5"}
element 3 Object {$ref="7"}
element 4 Object {$ref="9"}
element 5 Object {$ref="11"}
element 6 Object {$ref="13"}
element 7 Object {$ref="15"}
element 8 Object {$ref="17"}
element 9 Object {$ref="19"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change C# code:-

```
var ntf = ege.notifications.Where(u => u.UserID == uid).ToList();
        var collection = ntf.Select(x => new
        {
            ntitle = x.NotificationTitle,
            nlink = x.NotificationLink,
            nid = x.ID
        });
        Clients[connid].addData(collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into the following...

```
connection.addData = function (data) {
  // console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data)) // Print the output to the console
  var html = $.map(data, function (i, element) {
    return "<li>" + element.NotificationTitle + "<a href='" + element.NotificationLink + "'>Click Here</a><input type='hidden' value='" + element.ID + "' /> <a href='#' class='delnoti'>X</a> </li>";
  }).join("");

  $("#notiadd").append(html);

};
```

In this solution you create all the html upfront and add once to the DOM. This is a lot faster.

Hope this solves the problem you are having.

Comment: @BhavinPatolia Can you add the following line of code as the first line in the addData function and add the output to your question? **console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data))**